# How to give custom local maven repo in build.sbt

Tags: maven, sbt

Initially in build.sbt I  had

> resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file:///" + Path.userHome.absolutePath > + "/.m2"

when I was using default local maven repo. But I changed local maven repo to C:\m2. But how to give the new path in build.sbt ?
I tried various options to give C:\m2. But some how it always throw error as invalid arguments.

Answer (score 1):

As a general note, please write what version of sbt are you using, and the exact error message that you're seeing along with the stack traces etc.

> But how to give the new path in build.sbt?

The quick answer is to use u3 notation to maximize compatibility with current and previous RFCs (see [encoding file path as URI reference](http://eed3si9n.com/encoding-file-path-as-URI-reference) for more details), which looks like this:

```scala
resolvers += "Local Maven Repo" at "file:///C:/m2"
```

I've tried it on sbt 1.2.8 on Windows and it worked for me.